# TreeView с колонками

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть работающий TreeView и модель к нему. 
Но никак не получается загнать его в колонки (а точнее 3 колонки ). Код прилагается.

```
 <TreeView Name="treeViewGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
               Grid.Column="1">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                    <!--Item Source-->
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0">

                            </TextBlock>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="{Binding ServerVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}"  >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsServerSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Visibility="{Binding Equal, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}" 
                                             Grid.Column="0">
                                </RadioButton>

                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsServerSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                    <CheckBox.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Equal}" Value="True"/>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding LocalVisible}" Value="False"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </CheckBox.Style>
                                </CheckBox>

                                <TextBlock 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           Text="{Binding Server}"
                                           Grid.Column="1">
                                </TextBlock>

                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="{Binding LocalVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}">

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsLocalSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                             Visibility="{Binding Equal, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}" 
                                             IsEnabled="{Binding Path=!IsServerSelected}"
                                             Grid.Column="0">
                                </RadioButton>

                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsLocalSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                    <CheckBox.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Equal}" Value="True"/>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ServerVisible}" Value="False"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </CheckBox.Style>
                                </CheckBox>

                                <TextBlock 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                           Text="{Binding Local}" 
                                           Grid.Column="1">
                                </TextBlock>

                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>

                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildProperty}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0">
                                </TextBlock>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding ChildServerVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsServerSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Visibility="{Binding ChildEqual, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}" 
                                             Grid.Column="0">
                                    </RadioButton>

                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsServerSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                        <CheckBox.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ChildEqual}" Value="True"/>
                                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ChildLocalVisible}" Value="False"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </CheckBox.Style>
                                    </CheckBox>

                                    <TextBlock 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           Text="{Binding ChildServer}"
                                           Grid.Column="1">
                                    </TextBlock>

                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="2"  Visibility="{Binding ChildLocalVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsLocalSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                             Visibility="{Binding ChildEqual, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}" 
                                             Grid.Column="0"
                                             IsEnabled="{Binding Path=!IsServerSelected}" >
                                    </RadioButton>

                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsServerSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                        <CheckBox.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ChildEqual}" Value="True"/>
                                                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ChildServerVisible}" Value="False"/>
                                                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </CheckBox.Style>
                                    </CheckBox>

                                    <TextBlock 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                           Text="{Binding ChildLocal}" 
                                           Grid.Column="1">
                                    </TextBlock>

                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

А вот модель:

```
public class MergeTreeView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public bool Equal { get; set; }
    public bool ServerVisible { get; set; }
    public bool LocalVisible { get; set; }
    public List<Merge> Children { get; set; }
    bool IsComplex { get { return Children != null && Children.Any(); } }

    public MergeTreeView(string PropName, IPropertyRepresentation fromServer, IPropertyRepresentation local, IPropertyProvider provider)
    {
        this.Property = PropName;
        this.Server = fromServer == null ? " " : fromServer.GetStringValue;
        this.Local = local == null ? " " : local.GetStringValue;
        this.Equal = provider.Compare(fromServer, local);
        Children = Controller.GetDataForChild(fromServer == null ? null : fromServer.Children, local == null ? null : local.Children, provider);

        this.ServerVisible = fromServer != null;
        this.LocalVisible = local != null;
        mSelectedSide = ServerVisible ? SelectedSide.ServerSelected : SelectedSide.LocalSelected;
    }

    enum SelectedSide
    {
        LocalSelected,
        ServerSelected
    }
    private SelectedSide mSelectedSide;

    public bool IsLocalSelected
    {
        get
        { return mSelectedSide == SelectedSide.LocalSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value == IsLocalSelected)
                return;

            mSelectedSide = value ? SelectedSide.LocalSelected : SelectedSide.ServerSelected;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsLocalSelected");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsServerSelected");
        }
    }

    public bool IsServerSelected
    {
        get
        { return mSelectedSide == SelectedSide.ServerSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value == IsServerSelected)
                return;

            mSelectedSide = value ? SelectedSide.ServerSelected : SelectedSide.LocalSelected;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsLocalSelected");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsServerSelected");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример от MS здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms771523(v=vs.90).aspx